# Video not getting fitted to full screen in google chrome using video js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video.js

Aspect ratio is wrong on streams that don't have square pixels, but only on Chrome (tested on Win10 and OS X). It works as expected with Firefox and IE11 (on Win10).

```css
.videosize {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<video class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-custom videosize embed-responsive-item" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
    <source src="~/Videos/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

I can confirm it. In Safari and Firefox the sample works as expected, but in Chrome the aspect ratio is wrong. Using OS X 10.11.3.

[Google Chrome image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnm95.png)

[firefox Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2w63E.jpg)